# Сделать выпадающий список Google Таблицы

Tags: google-spreadsheet

Подскажите, как в Гугл Таблицах присвоить значениям из выпадающего списка айдишку? Пример на картинке. Слева первая таблица с названием товара и названием бренда, справа табличка названий брендов и присвоенным им айдишкам. Как сделать так, чтобы при выборе из выпадающего списка значения, в поле вставлялась айдишка выбранного значения, а не его название.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался! Нужно использовать функцию `=REGEXEXTRACT(Q2; "\d+")`.

Comment: Очень интересно каким образом у вас это получилось, можете подсказать?